# Criar uma variável tendo no seu nome outra variável (python)

Tags: python, variáveis

Estou realizando um trabalho na faculdade que consiste em analisar dados do covid-19 (através de uma planilha de excel). No entanto um dos quesitos que o meu prof. pede é que com indicação de uma determinada semana o programa deve disponibilizar para essa semana uma informação X e como sabem se passaram mais de 40 semanas desde o inicio do covid pelo que se eu ficar a criar subtuplos para cada semana e para cada coluna da aproximadamente umas 170 linhas de codigo somente de subtuplos, pelo que tentei dar uma variável tendo no seu nome outra variável, infelizmente não tive sucesso e gostaria da vossa ajuda.

```
import xlrd
a=xlrd.open_workbook("covid.xlsx")
b=a.sheet_by_name("dados")
x=b.col_values(2)

i=int(input("Qual o valor de i?"))
if i>0 and i<5:
    _0imar=x[i+(7(i-1)):i+(7*i-(i-1))]
    print(_0imar)
if i>=5 and i<10:
    _0iabr=x[i+(7(i-1)):i+(7*i-(i-1))]
#Restante dos meses

<>:11: SyntaxWarning: 'int' object is not callable;perhaps you missed a comma?
<>:14: SyntaxWarning: 'int' object is not callable; perhaps you missed a comma?
<>:11: SyntaxWarning: 'int' object is not callable; perhaps you missed a comma?
<>:14: SyntaxWarning: 'int' object is not callable; perhaps you missed a comma?
Qual o valor de i?2
<ipython-input-65-dc2ab15c45d9>:11: SyntaxWarning: 'int' object is not callable;perhaps you missed a
comma?
      _0imar=x[i+(7(i-1)):i+(7*i-(i-1))]
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-65-dc2ab15c45d9> in <module>
          9 i=int(input("Qual o valor de i?"))
         10 if i>0 and i<5:
    ---> 11     _0imar=x[i+(7(i-1)):i+(7*i-(i-1))]
         12     print(_0imar)
         13 if i>=5 and i<10:
    
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Obrigado.

Comment: Faça uma pausa no seu código, e estude sobre "dicionários" em Python  -
é o que vocẽ precisa aí: um único dicionário - não várias variáveis dinâmicas.

Comment: Já o erro que você está tendo não tem nada a ver com o nome de variável - é por que faltou o operador "*" para multiplicação na primeira parte da expressão: `[i+(7(i-1)):i+(7*i-(i-1))]` . Ler as mensagens de erro e entender o que estão dizendo também é fundamental para conseguir fazer qualquer coisa.

Comment: Pois de facto depois de colocar o "*" já funcionou, um erro mesmo estupido e de principiante, e também concordo com a utlização do dicionario torna mais simples eu que acabei por me baralhar devido a utilização do excel e nem acabei lembrando dos dicionários. Obrigado pela ajuda e pelo tempo

Comment: caso ainda queira utilizar o excel para que outras pessoas lhe envie dados, use o openpyxl, pra mim foi a melhor opção de lib.